# How can I utilize regular expressions for string formating in this scenario

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, amazon-web-services, formatting

I am writing a python script that will validate AWS IAM policies and want to know how to utilize Regular expressions for this use case.

I have this policy for example:

```
{'Action': ['s3:PutObject', 'kms:GenerateKey'],
'Effect': 'Allow'
'Resource': ['arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:<account_id>:key/*',
'arn:aws:s3:::bucket]}
```

I then have this code:

```
for value in policy:
    Resource = value['Resource']
    for resource in Resources:
        if resource == 'arn:aws:s3:::<bucket>'
        return True
```

In the case there's multiple S3 actions that are emitted to the policy, I would like to do something like this....

```
if resource =='arn:aws:s3:::<regular expression>'
```

With the regular expression being any character & integer. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean like `m = re.match(r'arn:aws:s3:::[a-zA-Z0-9]+$', resource)
if m:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do :

```
import re
if re.match(r'arn:aws:s3:::.*$', resource):
    ...
```

The `.` means any character, `*` means zero or more, `$` means to the end of the string.

You can replace `.` by `[a-zA-Z0-9]` if you only want letter and number not symbols.

You can also replace the `*` by `+` if you want at least one character (one or more)